# Special character at the end of commands

Tags: command-line, ls, special-characters, ps

Do commands like ls and ps actually end with a special character to indicate termination of response?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Legacy apps like ls and ps use a special character at the end which is used to determine the termination of response.

Comment: So why are you asking if you know the answer?

Comment: Because I don’t know what that character is

Comment: I assume you mean in terminal. You just press the enter key, surely.

Comment: There is no "special character", just <LF>

Comment: Every command returns an exit status (https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html), is it that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no "special" character in command output.

It is plain text ending with `0x0a` char that is Line Feed.

All previous lines of the output end with the same char.

Comment: I was talking about implicit characters. Like we don’t see them in the output.

Comment: There are none except the one I mentioned. All lines end with the same char.

Comment: And the whole output as well?

Comment: What do you mean? EACH line ends with the same char including the last. What is unclear?

Comment: I wasn’t talking about lines. My understanding is that when I type ls or ps is command line it gives an output which could be several lines + string of characters (special char or single character) which we don’t see but it is used to terminate the response. I don’t think that’s LF because it is used in between the lines. Correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: Also, its not in the output as we can’t see it!

Comment: You are wrong. You can easily find out yourself what is in any output using a hex editor.

Comment: Sometimes everything doesn’t show up in output like End of Transmission ascii characters and all. They are implicitly handled by the system.

Comment: Oh, FFS! Do `ps |& od -bc`. But it's up to the particular program what it outputs.